# How to create a database snapshot in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, snapshot

I used the below command to create a database snapshot in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
  CREATE DATABASE "dbss" ON  (
  NAME = "os-file-name",
  FILENAME = 'path')
  AS SNAPSHOT OF "dbName";
  GO
```

I got this error:

> Database Snapshot is not supported on Standard Edition (64-bit).

Does anyone knows how can I create a database snapshot in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: As the error message says, you're not allowed to create snapshots on Standard Edition. What do you need the snapshot for? Will a database backup suffice?

Comment: I'm running into this issue, too.  I'm on standard edition unfortunately, so I can't use snapshots either.  When you're talking about using a back up, you mean to restore it on a test server, THEN run DBCC on it?

Answer (score 8):

Database Snapshot is a feature of the Enterprise Edition and the 2008 Developer Edition.

Besides that there is only little use of Snapshots for a "common user". Most things can be done with a backup too.

Main purpose for snapshots are expensive queries on rapidly changing data. 
If you got a huge database and need to execute a query for a report that takes some time there is the danger that data may change while the query / procedure fetches data for the report. In this case you need snapshots. There you can query all your data without having problems with changing data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. yes the db backup does the job for me!